# Aparece un mensaje que no muestra la lista de la base de datos

Tags: jquery

Tengo un div donde muestra los listados provenientes de la base de datos automáticamente sin actualizer la página.

```
setInterval(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'atualizar-status.php',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(response) {
        $('#atualizarStatus').html(response);      
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

Pero me gustaría mostrarte un mensaje "Cargando..." antes de listar. Lo intenté de esa manera, pero el div sigue parpadeando.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $('#atualizarStatus').html('<p>Carregando...</p>');
});

setInterval(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'atualizar-status.php',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(response) {
        $('#atualizarStatus').html(response);      
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto? Perdóname mi español.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes el evento beforeSend y complete que te permite lanzar acciones antes y después de acabar de cargar te dejo un ejemplo

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://example.org",
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function () { // Before we send the request, remove the .hidden class from the spinner and default to inline-block.
                $('#loader').removeClass('hidden')
            },
            success: function (data) {
                // On Success, build our rich list up and append it to the #richList div.
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    let richList = "<ol>";
                    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        console.log(data[i].uri);
                        richList += "<li>" + data[i].uri + "</li>";
                    }
                    richList += "</ol>"
                    $('#richList').html(richList);
                }
            },
            complete: function () { // Set our complete callback, adding the .hidden class and hiding the spinner.
                $('#loader').addClass('hidden')
            },
        });
```